# Concatenate awk-output, string, and text file

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following two tab-separated files in my current directory.

**a.tsv**

```
do  not use this    line
but this    one
and that    too
```

**b.tsv**

```
three   fields  here
not here
```

For each tsv file there is an associated txt file in the same directory, with the same filename but different suffix.

**a.txt**

```
This is the a-specific text.
```

**b.txt**

```
Text associated to b.
```

For each pair of files I want to create a new file with the same name but the suffix _new.txt. The new files should contain all lines from the respective tsv file that contain exactly 3 fields, afterwards the string `\n####\n`, and then the whole content of the respective txt file. Thus, the following output files should be created.

## Desired output

**a_new.txt**

```
but this    one
and that    too

####
This is the a-specific text.
```

**b_new.txt**

```
three   fields  here

####
Text associated to b.
```

## Working, but bad solution

```
for file in ./*.tsv
do awk -F'\t' 'NF==3' $file > ${file//.tsv/_3_fields.tsv}
done

for file in ./*_3_fields.tsv
do cat $file <(printf "\n####\n") ${file//_3_fields.tsv/.txt} > ${file//_3_fields.tsv/_new.txt}
done
```

## Non-working code

I'd like to get the result with one script, and avoid creating the intermediate file with the suffix `_3_fields.tsv`.
I tried command substitution as follows:

```
for file in ./*.tsv
do cat <<< $(awk -F'\t' 'NF==3' $file) <(printf "\n####\n") ${file//.tsv/.txt} > ${file//.tsv/_new.txt}
done
```

But this doesn't write the awk-processed part into the new files.

Yet, the command substitution seems to work if I only write the awk-processed part into the new file like follows:

```
for file in ./*.tsv; do cat <<< $(awk -F'\t' 'NF==3' $file) > ${file//.tsv/_new.txt}; done
```

I'd be interested in why the second last code doesn't work as expected, and what a good solution would be to do the task.

Comment: It is good that you have shown your efforts, it will be very helpful for us to understand complete problem if you could post samples of input and expected output in your post with code tags.

Comment: I tried to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to redirect a sequence of commands

```
for file in ./*.tsv
do 
    {
        awk -F'\t' 'NF==3' "$file"
        printf "\n####\n"
        cat "${file//.tsv/.txt}"
    } > "${file//.tsv/_new.txt}"
done
```

Note that space after opening brace and  semicolon or newline before closing brace are important.

Seems also you are confusing command substitution `$()` and process substituion `<()` or `>()`. Also `<<<` is to redirect content as standard input whereas `<` to redirect a file.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, that simple. I was not aware that a sequence of commands can be redirected like that.